# Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\..\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll"

Tags: java, java-native-interface, titanium

Hello every time I open Titanium studio, this error pops up and I don't know the problem.

error: Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin..\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably indicated at installation time that this was the JDK to use for Titanium, and later updated to a newer version and deleted the old one.

Now Titanium tries to invoke the JVM in the JDK as told, and fails.  A probable fallback is to use the system java command if you have installed a JRE separately (so "java" works directly in a CMD.EXE session).

Comment: I don't indicate the JDK on installation and I was not asked to. but I think this is the problem....how could I reconfigure Titanium

Comment: A reinstallation perhaps?  The easiest is probably to reinstall the 1.7.40 JDK.

Comment: well yes you're correct instead I installed a 6u6 jdk which I know it's compatible and it worked. Thanks!